# database windows phone 7 reading XML records

Tags: xml, database, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I need as much help as I can get. I have a website and there is a table named rss with id_rss, id_katigoria, id_upokatigoria, and **linkrss** fields. In the field linkrss I have xml files. For example this link:  http://rss.in.gr/feed/news/world
Now I have a project to do for my university to build an app in windows phone 7. I want to read these XML files from my database **which is on the internet** (according to IDs that I want)
I know that I can't do SQL queries directly to my database, so I need something like WCF service? If yes, what is this? Is this the solution I am looking for? I want to start from somewhere. Please give me something. Explain to me, if it is possible from someone, where to start, what should I read and so on.

I found this tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400697/WCF-Service-Creation-With-Csharp

Is this what I am looking for? But, in the end, the output is in command line. I do not want that. I want to show me the articles from the XML to the simulator.

I am using XAMPP for my website and phpMyAdmin

P.S. I have done lots of windows phone 7 apps, but this is my first time that I want to connect database from Internet to wp7 app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need a WebService,a WebService in rest could be your solution, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426769/Creating-a-REST-service-using-ASP-NET-Web-API

Comment: Hi again, thank you for your answer, but I couldn't find a way to solve it, using webservice. So, I did it with XML files. Now I have another problem on that. In the field description of XML file, there is also an img tag in it. How can I grab this image out of description and see it like an image and not like a string, that I am seeing it now? There is a link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649759/how-to-separate-img-tags-in-description-of-xml-rss-feed 
but I couldn't understand so much..